# Can't generate signed apk because gradle failes for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I can't generate a signed release apk due to the following error in Gradle built.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Entry name 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata' collided
```

but there is no problem with running my app on a device. I have tried invalidating caches and restarting, deleting old generated debug/release apks.
One additional action I have done in Gradle is that, I have applicationIdSuffix, versionNameSuffix, and sperate name for debug and release builds. My Gradle buildTypes for app module goes like this

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the build variant from "debug" to "release"